# How to send an object via routeparams in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-routing, routeparams

I want to send an object via routeparams to another page using angular 5, but it isn't working.

Take a look at the code that I have written below :

```
<button mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['./view-class-timing-set',newObject]">New</button>
```

TS code for object :

```
newObject = {
 id: 123
}
```

Module code :

```
{
path: 'ng2/ClassTimingSet',
component: ClassTimingSetComponent,

children: [
  { path: '', component: NewClassTimingSetComponent},
  { path: 'view-class-timing-set/:newClassTimingObj', component: ViewClassTimingSetComponent}
]
```

},

TS CODE to display the object once the page is routed:

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(
  params =>{
    console.log('THis is the object that I got');
    console.log(params);
  }

)
```

}

However, page is not getting routed it says :

```
 Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'ng2/ClassTimingSet/view-class-timing-set;id=123'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `queryParams` instead. This is not a valid object in your url, and passing objects as usual url params is generally not a good idea. Just make your URL

```
{ path: 'view-class-timing-set', component: ViewClassTimingSetComponent}
```

(we do not need to indicate that a route can have query parameters, those are usually arbitrary)

Then in your component:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
  params => {
      console.log('THis is the object that I got');
       console.log(params);
  }
```

And visit the url like this: `ng2/ClassTimingSet/view-class-timing-set?id=123&key1=value1&key2=value2`